# Nginx serving Angular returns 404

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm trying to run a production-built **Angular** app through **nginx**.
Currently, I can serve the index.html just fine but the issue is for all the *.js and *css referenced as sources inside the index itself, those return a 404 error.
I've been going back and forth between different configs using root or alias but none seem to do the trick.

First, I'm building the app using:

```
ng build --configuration production --aot
```

*Note: The above command results in the creation of a **dist** folder with all the necessary files to run the app, I then move all those files to the path **/apps/customer-ui***

Folder structure is as follows:

```
/apps
  /customer-ui
    /index.html
    /(all other files resulting from build)
```

This is my nginx.conf

```
...

http {

    ...
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /apps;
        index index.html;
        
        location / { }
        
        location ^~/customer-ui {
            alias /apps/customer-ui/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /customer-ui/index.html =404;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Currently, accessing http://localhost/customer-ui returns the correct index but also the above mentioned 404s, because the references are pointing to http://localhost/filename.js instead of http://localhost/customer-ui/filename.js

[Console errors here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2vGt.png)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the necessary files are inside `customer-ui` directory, it's better to point all paths there, like so:

```
        root /apps/customer-ui;
        index index.html;
        
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
```

Alternatively, you can use this (not recommended since it's rather confusing):

```
        root /apps;
        index index.html;
        
        location / {
            alias /apps/customer-ui/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention on the original post, I'm looking to host two Angular apps (customer-ui and admin-ui), their paths are /app/ui-name and I want them to be acessible via localhost/ui-name. Is it possible to setup this scenario on nginx?

Comment: @AndreFidalgo It's possible, the apps would need to be compiled with correct path for their assets. Nginx can't help with that.